# Laravel return model with if statement

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create offers and assign them to parent categories, to be more specific i have an Offer model and inside the offer model i have this many to many relationship

```
   public function category() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
```

I want the above function to return ONLY the categories which have NULL parent_category which mean they are the parent categories. Is it possible with the above code?

Comment: can you show query which you tried

Comment: check has and doesntHave statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the entire scope of your project, I'd suggest one of the following: either change the name of the relation (A) or keep the relation as is and query it when you need it (B).

Option A -

```
public function childCategory() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->whereNull('parent_category');
}
```

Option B -

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}

$offer = Offer::with('category')
    ->whereHas('category' function ($query) {
        $query->whereNull('parent_category');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->where('parent_category', null);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.